# Zoom out in the html template for gmail app on Iphone

Tags: html, media-queries, html-email, email-client, email-templates

I am working on a html email template for my company. I have a zoom out problem which is making some part of the html email template look smaller than the other.

I use the following media query

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 380px) {

    .mobileWidth {
      width: 290px !important; 
    }

    img { 
    max-width: 130px !important;
    max-height: 130px !important;
    }       

     .test {
       width: 290px !important;
       text-align: center !important;
     }

    .hideMobile {
      display: none;
    }           
  }
```

The email is divided into three parts:
1) text which is 4-5 lines

```
      text
      text
      text
      text
```

2) An Image a small image and text

```
      -------------
      |           |      text 1
      |           |      text 2
      |   img1    |      text 3
      |           |      text 4
      -------------
```

3) three bigger images:

```
                      ---------------------
                     |                    |      
                     |                    |      
                     |                    |      
                     |                    |
                     |       img2         |
                     |                    |
                     |                    |
                     |                    |
                     |                    |
                      ---------------------      


                     ---------------------
                     |                    |      
                     |                    |      
                     |                    |      
                     |                    |
                     |       img3         |
                     |                    |
                     |                    |
                     |                    |
                     |                    |
                      ---------------------   



                      ---------------------
                     |                    |      
                     |                    |      
                     |                    |      
                     |                    |
                     |       img4         |
                     |                    |
                     |                    |
                     |                    |
                     |                    |
                      ---------------------
```

The problem I face is the media query works fine for the iPhone inbuilt mail accounts.

The problem is with the gmail app for the iPhone. The part 1 and part2 of the email are too zoomed out like to about 60-65% and the part3 is just fine.

And I am using the most primitive way of html coding doing inline CSS as most of the email clients strip of an external CSS file.

I cannot post the code here as I have a strict NDA, but I assume this must be a common problem to all who are coding an email template. Any tips or pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail strips the media queries so if a user is viewing the email on a mobile device through the Gmail app, they will receive the desktop view.